# Function always returning null

Tags: sql, sql-server

I created a function, that needs two numbers and type of operation to calculate the result. Unfortunately, all results of this function are null.

```
CREATE FUNCTION DBO.CALC
    (@NUMBER1 FLOAT, @OPERATION VARCHAR, @NUMBER2 FLOAT)
RETURNS FLOAT
BEGIN
    DECLARE @RESULT FLOAT

    SET @RESULT = CASE  
                     WHEN @OPERATION = 'DODAWANIE' THEN @NUMBER1 + @NUMBER2
                     WHEN @OPERATION = 'ODEJMOWANIE' THEN @NUMBER1 - @NUMBER2
                     WHEN @OPERATION = 'MNOZENIE' THEN @NUMBER1 * @NUMBER2
                     WHEN @OPERATION = 'DZIELENIE' THEN @NUMBER1 / @NUMBER2
                     ELSE NULL
                  END

    RETURN @RESULT
END

SELECT 
    DBO.CALC(2, 'DODAWANIE', 1), 
    DBO.CALC(2, 'ODEJMOWANIE', 1),
    DBO.CALC(2, 'MNOZENIE', 1), 
    DBO.CALC(2, 'DZIELENIE', 1)
```

Comment: Because `@OPERATION VARCHAR` is the same as `@OPERATION VARCHAR(1)` and therefore truncates your input. **ALWAYS** set the length when using `varchar`/`nvarchar`.

Comment: Thank u very much!

Comment: You should look at inline Table-Valued Functions, they are much faster

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the `LENGTH` while using `VARCHAR` so in your function you need to add `LENGTH` to `@OPERATION VARCHAR(LENGTH)`:

```
CREATE FUNCTION DBO.CALC(@NUMBER1 FLOAT, @OPERATION VARCHAR(LENGTH), @NUMBER2 FLOAT)
RETURNS FLOAT
BEGIN
DECLARE @RESULT FLOAT
SET @RESULT =CASE 
            WHEN @OPERATION ='DODAWANIE' THEN @NUMBER1 +@NUMBER2
            WHEN @OPERATION ='ODEJMOWANIE' THEN @NUMBER1-@NUMBER2
            WHEN @OPERATION ='MNOZENIE' THEN @NUMBER1*@NUMBER2
            WHEN @OPERATION ='DZIELENIE' THEN @NUMBER1/@NUMBER2
            ELSE NULL
        END
RETURN @RESULT
END

SELECT DBO.CALC(2,'DODAWANIE',1), DBO.CALC(2,'ODEJMOWANIE',1),
    DBO.CALC(2,'MNOZENIE',1), DBO.CALC(2,'DZIELENIE',1)
```